# Django REST framework range filter

Tags: django, filter, range, django-rest-framework

How can I do a range filter for dates and number in Django REST Framework? Other filters (lt, gt etc.) work fine.  I tried many variants such as:

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters

class OrderFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    total_price__range = filters.RangeFilter(name='total_price')
    created_at__range = filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(name='created_at')
    ....
    class Meta:
        model = Order

        fields = {
            'created_at__range': ['__all__'],
            'total_price__range': ['__all__'],
            ...
            }

class OrderViewSet(BaseViewSet, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_class = OrderFilter
    ....
```

In the browsable api there are to fields when I click on bottom "Filters", Then url looks like:

```
/orders/?created_at__range_0=2017-05-22&created_at__range_1=2017-05-22
```

and it doesn't work. I need something like

```
/orders/?created_at__range=2017-05-22,2017-05-24
```

and same with integer:

```
/orders/?total_price__range=1000,2000
```

It was described [here](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#caveats--limitations) .

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you've got `total_price` as your field name but you're URL says `total_cost`.

Second, remove the `__range` suffix from your filter names. Anything with `__` is part of the Django filtering. For example, if you were querying a model in Django for a value greater than something you'd do:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(price__gte=50)
```

Note the `__gte` suffix; That's how Django does filter modifiers. So your class should be something like:

```
class OrderFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    total_price = filters.RangeFilter(name='total_price')
    # ...
```

Then you can apply range filtering on that field in the query.

Comment: Thank you for so fast reply and revision.  There is no `total_cost`, only `total_price`, my error. Now I tried: 
`total_price = filters.RangeFilter(name='total_price')`

but in this case is possible to do only request with params, that doesn't works. 

`/orders/?total_price_0=1000&total_price_1=5000`

Is possible to do request like: 

`/orders/?total_price_range=1000,5000` ?

Comment: https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#caveats--limitations - here is described why it desnt' works... possible sollution: "Use a CSV-based filter such as those derived from BaseCSVFilter/BaseInFilter/BaseRangeFilter" How can I use it?