# Using gte, lte, and range with Django REST Framework

Tags: django, rest, frameworks, lte

Has anyone successfully used DRF to make API calls using gte, lte, and range? If so, what extension did you use? I've tried django-filters and django-rest-framework-filters but neither work as stated. If someone can share their code that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is not working with the filters? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182268/67579

Comment: Thanks, I've gotten it to work now. Is there a way to replace the __ (double underscore) with a single underscore when applying a filter to a field? For example, instead of 

score__range=x,y 

I would like to use 

score_range=x,y

so the Django REST URL is more user friendly. Thanks.